# Dependency management with OSGi

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I want to develop a multi-module application according to `OSGi` specification. Let's assume that one of my modules uses `Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1`. Spring provides a bundled version of `Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1` in their repository, so I can add the corresponding dependency in my POM.

If I install my bundle in `Apache Felix` for example, is it right that the dependency to `Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1` will not be resolved until I install the bundle of `Apache Commons Logging 1.1.1` as well? My bundle will try to import a package that hasn't been exported.

I don't really understand how dependency management works in the `OSGi` world. Should I install every bundle that my application needs? Also, I don't understand how it integrates with Maven?

Thanks in advance for your explanations

---

**EDIT**: I've seen there is a subproject of Apache Felix called OBR that seems to facilitate bundles management (e.g. deployment). But, we already have a Maven architecture with local repositories, private repositories... How is OBR integrated to Maven?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use OSGi together with maven then I recommend Apache Karaf as a server which can use the Felix OSGi framework. The advantage is that you can install bundles directly from maven repositories using mvn: urls.

If you just use Apache Karaf with a maven repo then you have no transitive resolution at runtime. You have to install all bundles you need. What helps a lot is that karaf has the concept of features. So you can use the features as coarse grained building blocks. You can also create your own features where you refer to other features and bundles. This allows to install your whole app with one command.

Felix and Karaf also support OBR but you would have to create your own OBR Repo. There are currently no public OBR repos. The advantage of OBR is that it can resolve most of the transitive dependencies. The Karaf features even work together with OBR so you can just list some top level bundles in the feature and let OBR resolve the rest.

In practice I have good experiences with simple Karaf features without OBR. It is some manual work but less than you would expect and works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

OSGi dependencies are based on Java packages: when a bundle states that it needs to import a given package (indicating a range of versions that are acceptable), the framework will attempt to "wire" that import to a suitable version of that package, that must be exported by another bundle.

If the package cannot be found, the bundle won't be resolved and cannot be started - so yes you'll need to install all bundles that your application requires, and as Christian indicates there are various tools that can help you with that.

A simple way to get the required bundles is to use the maven-dependencies-plugin to grab the bundles from Maven's list of dependencies and copy them somewhere where your app can find them at startup to install them, as done in [2] (in launcher/pom.xml), a small example app that I wrote.

You could also use Sling's maven-launchpad-plugin [3] to generate a runnable jar file that embeds the OSGi framework and all bundles that you need, and sets up everything at startup.

About the import and exports - without going into details, assuming you use the maven-bundle-plugin [1] to build your bundles, you'll specify what packages you want your bundle to export (others will be invisible to other bundles), and the maven-bundle-plugin will generate (in most cases automatically, but you can override that as needed) the list of packages to import, so there's usually not much work if your own code is cleanly split between packages that you want to export and internal implementation packages.

[1] http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

[2] https://github.com/bdelacretaz/OSGi-for-mere-mortals

[3] http://sling.apache.org/site/maven-launchpad-plugin.html