# Best practise to use third party libraries in JBoss OSGI

Tags: jboss, osgi, jboss-eap-6

First of all I'm an OSGI newbie :-)

I'm trying to build an OSGI application in JBoss EAP 6.1. But I currently have problems with OSGI third party libraries.

I need the following package "javax.enterprise.context". So I have added "weld-osgi-bundle-1.2.0.Beta1.jar" to the deployments folder. When i started my application I got the error that the package "javax.interceptor" wasn't available. So I have added the following config the my configuration xml:

```
<capability name="javax.inject.api"/>
<capability name="javax.interceptor.api"/>
```

Then I needed the package "org.jboss.weld.environment.osgi.api.annotation", so I added "weld-osgi-core-extension-1.2.0.Beta1.jar" to my deployments folder. But then I got the error that the package "ch.qos.logback.classic" wasn't available....

So my question is, what is the best way to depend on third party lirbaries in jboss osgi? 
In a "normal" ear file everything is packaged within that ear, is there a way to do this with osgi bundles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to embed your dependencies within the OSGi bundle. Take a look at [Bundle-ClassPath](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-ClassPath) manifest entry. You may also want to look at [OBR](http://www.osgi.org/download/rfc-0112_BundleRepository.pdf) for bundle dependency management.

Finally, please read a similar [post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435840/dependency-management-with-osgi)